# How to get IPv4 address from already connected router via wifi

Tags: android, networking, tcp, ip, ipv4

I want to make `tcp/ip` connection between my router and android device. I already connect to specific wifi network. But I also need to get IPv4 address from my router to establish `tcp/ip` connection. Is it possible to get IPv4 address if I'm already connected. Here's my code. How do I connect to my router.

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> list = scanner.getScanResults();

        for(ScanResult result : list){
            if(result.SSID.equals("Micro")){
                //Connect to THIS network
                connect(result.SSID);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void connect(String name){
        String password = "myPassword";
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + name + "\"";
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ password +"\"";

        scanner.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = scanner.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + name + "\"")) {
                scanner.disconnect();
                scanner.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                scanner.reconnect();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my clien class
public class TCPClient {

```
private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVER_IP = "xxx.xxx.x.xx"; // computer IP address
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 4444;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean run = false;
private PrintWriter out;
private BufferedReader in;

/**
 *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    run = false;
}

public void run() {

    run = true;

    try {
        // computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        try {

            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (run) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();
                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

    // Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    // class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

So for now I have hard coded my IP address but how can I get from connected device?

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to run a dhcp client or send the DHCP message from your application. An easy alternative to see make it work fast is to assign a static IP address but this is not recommended as there could be IP collision.

Comment: Ok, but how can I send DHCP messages?

Comment: @David, It seems there is no API for that. You can implement your own DHCP client and then configure the network interface